# AngularJS: how does ng-include with a dynamic scope variable work?

Tags: angularjs

I'm implementing something where the view changes based on the selected value of a select dropdown. I'm doing this using `ng-include="mySelectedValue"`, which is attached to `<select ng-model="mySelectedValue" ng-options="..."></select>` tags.

Just wondering what happens under the hood, because this is essentially a `SPA` with no routes that is being loaded inside one of my Rails apps.

When the app gets loaded, does it just load all the views in the browser somehow? I don't get how angular works so magically. Would love to know how views are popping up when there are no server calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume mySelectedValue is a src.

According to Angular Docs:

> By default, the template URL is restricted to the same domain and
>   protocol as the application document. This is done by calling
>   $sce.getTrustedResourceUrl on it.

$sce.getTrustedResourceUrl is basically an ajax request to fetch the corresponding template. So your server call is here :)

After that, there goes the $compile for the template, and renders the view.